# How do I let data in 1 column power the content of the 2nd column in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a list of users in the left column, generated by `<%= current_user.clients %>` and the second column is empty by default.

However, when the user clicks on one of the links, the second column becomes populated with the projects associated with that user - without the entire page being reloaded (i.e. using AJAX).

I would also like to continue the process, so when they click on a project from that user, the third column is populated with other things (e.g. the name of images, etc.).

How do I accomplish this in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Rails 3 and jQuery (I'm not well-versed in prototype).  It's easy to switch jQuery for prototype in Rails 3: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

For the link:

```
<a href="#" class="first_column_link" data-client-id="<%= client.id %>">Something</a>
```

Using JavaScript and jQuery, write a function that sucks in links of class `first_column_link` (please rename to something more reasonable, by the way):

```
$(function() {
  $('.first_column_link').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/clients/' + $(this).attr('data-client-id'), function(data) {
      // Populate the second column using the response in data
    });
  });
});
```

This doesn't work on browsers that don't support or have otherwise disabled JavaScript.  Gracefully degrading would likely be a good idea, but without more context, I can't advise you how to best do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to_remote current_user.clients, go_to_controller_path %>
```

Proceed from there.

go_to_controller_path routes to an action which renders javascript to update the 2nd column (probably with a partial).

Comment: Was really looking for a bit more details. I am noobish to Rails, so if you could provide some more info, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not a fan of link_to_remote - depends on javascript being present

Comment: So what are you a fan of Sir Omar :) Do tell, please.

Comment: See Andys answer - that is where I would go, though, id start off with getting it to work without javascript first.